# StringBuilder substring misbehavior

Tags: java

```
public class Demo234234 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String s = "aa";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
        System.out.println(sb);
        
        sb.append("bb");
        System.out.println(sb);
        
        sb.substring(s.length());
        System.out.println(sb); // Here I expected as "bb", but getting "aabb", why?
        System.out.println(sb.substring(s.length()));
        
    }

}
```

Output:

```
aa
aabb
aabb
bb
```

I expected output as "bb" for the line `System.out.println(sb);`, but instead getting as "aabb", may  know why?

`sb.append("bb");` behaves properly, then why not `sb.substring(s.length());`?

**One more thing to ask**: which is better to use? stringObj.substring ()  or stringBuilder.substring () ??

Comment: `sb.substring` *returns* a substring, it doesn't change the string(builder) in place.

Comment: About your addition, leaving aside the fact that you should ask one question per post, what is `stringObj`?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca when  sb.append("bb"); behaving properly, then why not sb.substring(s.length());??

Comment: @RobertHarvey when  sb.append("bb"); behaving properly, then why not sb.substring(s.length());??

Comment: Because you're printing what it returns. Print `sb` again just after that, you'll see it's still `aabb`.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca some string object.. I can substring() method in both String and StringBuilder classes, then which is better to use and why?

Comment: It's called a `StringBuilder`, not a `StringDismantler`.

Comment: You use `String` and `StringBuilder` for different purposes. The question on whether to use `String.substring` or `StringBuilder.substring` doesn't make much sense. The actual question is whether to use `String` or `StringBuilder`, to which the answer is "depends on what you need it for". Need to modify the content or append to it a lot? `StringBuilder` is probably what you want.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Iam printing even after sb.substring() too, but getting different output, but its printing correct output, after sb.append()

Comment: You should *really* read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)... There's no reason two methods doing two different things should behave the same way. `substring` doesn't modify the string(builder). That's a fact.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca okay now got it, sry I thought sb.substring() returning a StringBuilder object... Thanks for thee link..

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca but why substring() added in StringBuilder class too, I think having substring alone in String class is enough, right?

Comment: @john because if you have a `StringBuilder` you have a `StringBuilder`, not a `String`. So I guess the answer is convenience. Again, `StringBuilder` and `String` serve different purposes and are not interchangeable, so it's not like having the same methods in both classes is robbing any of them of their purpose.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca okay Thanks for clarifying :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a `StringBuilder` the `substring(int start)` method returns a new `String` but doesn't change the `StringBuilder` object itself, so you should save its result to a variable of type `String`.

```
String ss = sb.substring(s.length());
System.out.println(ss);
```